# Is Windows 7 Home better for small notebook than Professional

Tags: windows-7, laptop

I have quite small Asus Notebook (Intel Atom 1.6GHz, 2GB RAM)

I have installed Windows 7 Professional edition on it, but it works slow sometimes (even with Aero and unnecessary services disabled). I have feeling, that preinstalled W7 Starter worked much faster.

Do you think, that installing Windows 7 Home edition will speed up this computer a little?

And if yes, will home basic be faster than home premium? I want only basic browser/Office functionality.

Comment: do you mean 2 GB of RAM?

Comment: Yes, 2GB of RAM operating memory

Comment: There is no performance difference between `Windows 7 Home Premium` and `Windows 7 Professional`

Comment: I really hope this is not considered a troll, but have you considered ditching Windows on it and running a lightweight Linux distribution (For example Linux Mint)- this will give you (for example) Firefox, Chrome and LibreOffice office suite, and will be MUCH faster.

Comment: @davidgo If it will be my laptop: Yes, I would do that. But its my wives and she has to have Microsoft Office. Besides LibreOffice sometimes messes up docx and pttx documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely not.  Home editions are not much different than Professional.

The Starter Edition is designed to work on netbooks, while the other editions are designed primarily for laptops and dekstops.

Starter edition is more than capable of running Office and using the web.